# Referring to subform record in access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have the following form, with three subforms:

[image]

The button on the top right opens a userform in excel. I would like that userform to already have some of the **selected** values from these subforms. However, I am unable to refer to the records in the subforms in my VBA code. I've been successful in transferring the values from the main form, such as name etc. but not the ones from the subform. Code in access:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Toggle159_Click()
    Dim abc As String
    abc = Me.CompanyName

    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application, xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\NA\eb\quotegenv2.xlsm") ' specify file
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.Run "Module3.showFormWithValues", abc


End Sub
```

In the above code, CompanyName is a control on the mainform. This code runs fine but I've tried to refer to items in the subform using 'me.subformname.form.controlname' but the control name does not appear in the suggestions.

Code in excel for the module:

```
' placed in code Module3
    Sub showFormWithValues(txt1 As String)
        With UserForm1

            .ClientName.Text = txt1

        End With
    UserForm1.Show
    End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to set `ClientName` before the form is open.

Use a global variable at the top of module 3 to share the data between `showFormWithValues` and the form.

At the top of `Module3` before the first procedure as a public variable as the example below shows: -

```
Option Explicit

Public StrCN    As String

Sub showFormWithValues(txt1 As String)
    ...
End Eub
```

In `UserForm1` add (or update if it already exists) the following: -

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Me.ClientName.Text = Module3.StrCN
End Sub
```

Comment: The code provided works fine because it refers to an item on the main form. What I'm having difficulty with is referring to the items in the subforms.

Comment: But you didn't show where that was failing did you? Or have missed something? Pass the subform options through like you did the client name? Or use access to drop them into a sheet in the Excel workbook that can then be used in Excel?

Comment: Having trouble with the syntax to refer to items in the subform. Could you be more specific on how to do that in access vba?